# Box<dyn> and Arc<dyn> in multiple threads situation

Tags: rust

i have code below, it is a threadpool implementation, type Job is my problem:

```
pub struct ThreadPool {
    workers:Vec<Worker>,
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Job>
}

type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

impl ThreadPool {
    pub fn new (size: usize) -> ThreadPool {
        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(size);
        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));
        for id in 0..size {
            workers.push(Worker::new(id, Arc::clone(&receiver)));
        }
        ThreadPool{ workers, sender }
    }

    pub fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce()->() + Send + 'static,
    {
        &self.sender.send(Box::new(f)).unwrap();
    }
}

struct Worker {
    id:usize,
    thread: thread::JoinHandle<Arc<Mutex<Receiver<Job>>>>
}
impl Worker {
    fn new(id:usize, reciever:Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {

        let thread = thread::spawn( move || loop {
            let job = reciever.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            println!("Worker {id} got a job; executing.");
            job()
        });

        Worker { id, thread }
    }
}
```

the code above can work well and type Job is defined by Box.

then i tried to define type Job by Arc,

```
type Job = Arc<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;
```

the code shows error below:

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src\lib.rs:36:22
    |
36  |         let thread = thread::spawn( move || loop {
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)`
    = note: required for `Arc<(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)>` to implement `Send`
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required for `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Arc<(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)>>` to implement `Send`
    = note: required for `Mutex<std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Arc<(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)>>>` to implement `Sync`
    = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
    = note: required for `Arc<Mutex<std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<Arc<(dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static)>>>>` to implement `Send`
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
```

i think Arc is a thread safe smart pointer, why i can not replace Arc with Box?

Comment: Your code does not generate any errors. Please post a minimal **reproducible** example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Arc` is not always thread-safe, it is only `Send` and `Sync` if the type inside is `Send` and `Sync`. This is because it can be used to access data from threads other than the thread created it. `dyn FnOnce() + Send` is obviously `Send`, but not `Sync`. Replace it with `dyn FnOnce() + Send + Sync`.